# Bash script, update output once command is ended

Tags: bash, shell

I have tried different ways but none of them have worked so far.

```
echo "Starting"

checklocation(){
if (command blabla)

then locationOne=$"Found"

else locationOne=$"Not found"

fi

}
checklocation &

echo "Let's check: " $locationOne

echo "Ending"
```

As my command take long time to provide the results I'd like to proceed to print all the output and show the value of $locationOne once the result is ready. The following code works fine printing all the output at once however the $locationOne doesn't appear. I tried with printf and \r too without luck. Any suggestions?

To clarify, I would like to load the variable value where the arrows are pointing once the command completes

[image: Link to the image]

Comment: The `echo "Let's check: " $locationOne` is probably happening before `command blabla` finishes in background.

Comment: `$locationOne once the result is ready` - so output it to a file. Then print the file content.

Comment: @PaulHodges I tried to add a sleep command after last echo too but $locationOne is not displayed

Comment: @KamilCuk are you aware of any way to do it without a file?

Comment: First off, you need to `return` a value from your function. Secondly, you need to capture that in your main program. Thirdly, you need to use `echo -n` to leave the cursor at the end of the line, pending output from your function...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Functions don't have return values. They have output, and they have exit statuses.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, ...though `echo -n ...` is better replaced with `printf %s '...'`, as the former isn't strictly POSIX-specified. As from the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html: *It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go back and amend screen output later.

This is very difficult in the general case, but you can simplify it dramatically by making sure that the output you write doesn't scroll the screen in such a way that it's hard to predict where the amendment will have to be made.

This example does it by clearing the screen first, so that any extra output is unlikely to scroll. It can then update by coordinates:

```
#!/bin/bash

check() {
  sleep 3
  tput sc        # Save cursor
  tput cup 1 14  # Set y,x coordinates
  printf '%s' "Found"
  tput rc        # Restore cursor
}
check &
clear # Clear screen so we know where we are
echo "Starting"
echo "Let's check: "
echo "Ending"
wait
```

This shows:

```
Starting
Let's check:  
Ending
```

for three seconds, then it updates it to:

```
Starting
Let's check:  Found
Ending
```

Alternative approaches include:

- Keeping the data you want on screen in a string, and just clearing+writing whenever you want to update the full screen
- Tracking the number of lines you write, then using the "cursor up" ANSI command (`tput cuu`) to move up to where you believe the line to amend will be.

Comment: I can't change the order of the output I am afraid, also the script needs to be run on Mac OS X with a standard software configuration

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. You want the program to continue without waiting, and then when the output is ready, to go back to where the previous console output was and amend it on screen. That's significantly harder.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean @that other guy! The following script does what I want however it stops everything before printing last echo:

#!/bin/bash
sek=5
echo "$sek Seconds Wait!"
while [ $sek -ge 1 ]
do
   echo -ne "One Moment please $sek ... \r"
   sleep 1
   sek=$[$sek-1]
done
echo
echo "ready!"

Comment: Ok, I added an example

Comment: Your example works very well thank you! Everything works as it should however when I try to apply the same code in three different part of the same script the ouput gets messy as the cursor doesn't follow the location I gave it.

Comment: For example

`sentence 1
sentence 2
sentence 3`

If 3 takes too long to be calculated, I don't know why but 2 appears where 3 should appear and then the output get messy

Comment: Unfortunately the format here is shown all in one line, anyhow the problem is that the cursor goes up and down by itself

Comment: It's very tricky to get right, yes. Consider just redrawing the entire screen every time.

Comment: I think that the issue is due to the fact that I had to add a sleep for each of them, sleep 1 sleep 2 and sleep 3

Comment: You have to be careful and make sure that save/move/restore happens atomically, and only after the rest of the script's output so that the coordinates are valid at that time

Comment: I think I have solved removing the sleep for the last two and starting the first calling the second, calling the third...so far it works fine. Thank you @that other guy you have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Starting"

checklocation(){
if (command blabla)
then
locationOne="Found"
else 
locationOne="Not found"
fi
}
echo "Calling function"
checklocation
echo "Let's check: " $locationOne
echo "Ending"
```

try following the above corrections,

Remove the "**$**" when assigning the **locationOne** variable

Also while calling the function remove "**&**", ignore this it is considered as an argument.

Goodluck !!

Comment: I have added & to allow the script to go ahead and don't wait for the results of checklocation

Comment: @Porcac1x Yes, but as your question says...you want to show it once it's ready... so you'll have to wait. Also `locationOne` is local to your function.

Comment: @MarkSetchell hey Mark, I'd like to show just LocationOne when the result is ready but everything (including Let's check) before the result is ready

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wait` to wait till child process status is changed. (check `man wait`)

```
#for demo puposes , I have manually added sleep of 10 sec. 
long_running_command()
{
sleep 10
echo "Hey, I am long running command....uh"
}

long_running_command &                 #<-using & to send this function to BG
echo "I am normal command"
wait                                   #waiting till the child is terminated.
```

The above script will result in the following output:

```
I am normal command
Hey, I am long running command....uh
```

Comment: This will invert the order though :(